# How to remove drag(Ghost) image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to remove ghost image when drag the image. We have tried code, its working in Firefox and chrome but not working in Safari. Please any one help what is the mistake of my code.
https://jsfiddle.net/rajamsr/Lfuq5qb6/

```
document.addEventListener("dragstart", function( event ) {
      dragged = event.target;
      event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(dragged, 11111110, 10);
}, false);
```

Comment: this code right here is jumping my memory to 100% when i start to drag the image, is it supposed to do that, and why do you want to hide the image drag??

Answer (score 35):

You can prevent showing the ghost preview by showing empty/transparent image:

```
document.addEventListener("dragstart", function( event ) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=';
    event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 0, 0);
}, false);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work well for Chromium browsers, it still shows a little "globe" icon.

Comment: @MyLyck you should create img before dragstart event, actually when you set drag image your image should loaded

Comment: @MasoodZamani thanks putting the img outside of the react component made the global icon go away

Answer (score 6):

You could just use the `event.target` and position it using the window's `outerWidth` and `outerHeight`

```
document.addEventListener("dragstart", function( event ) {
  event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(event.target, window.outerWidth, window.outerHeight);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not use the `event.target` as an argument to `setDragImage`, this is probably causing the memory issues here.

You can always add a custom image, the image could as well be a transparent PNG.

Here is an example how that goes.

```js
var dragMe = document.getElementById("drag-me"),
    img = new Image();

img.onload = function () {

  dragMe.addEventListener("dragstart", function(e) {

    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 0, 0);

  }, false);

}

img.src = "http://placehold.it/150/000000/ffffff?text=GHOST";
```

```css
#drag-me {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

#drag-me > img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="drag-me">
  <img src="https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" draggable="true" />
</div>
```

Another option would be to just clone the node element and set its `visibility` to `hidden`. But for this option to work it is necessary to add the cloned element to the DOM.

An example with the cloned node could look like this. I am not hiding the node completely, so you can see what is happening.

```js
var dragMe = document.getElementById("drag-me");

dragMe.addEventListener("dragstart", function(e) {

    var clone = this.cloneNode(true);
    clone.style.opacity = 0.1;               // use opacity or
    //clone.style.visibility = "hidden";     // visibility or
    //clone.style.display = "none";          // display rule
    document.body.appendChild(clone);
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(clone, 0, 0);
    
}, false);
```

```css
#drag-me {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

#drag-me > img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="drag-me">
  <img src="https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" draggable="true" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

JSfiddle no longer opens so I don't understand the context but works for me in Chrome

```
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(canvas, 0, 0);
canvas.remove();
```

Comment: this still shows the little globe icon

Answer (score -1):

Your code is causing memory issues.

Instead use css to stop user-drag/select, this works in most browsers but there is a bug it seems in firefox that it doesn't work so add `ondragstart="return false;"` to `img` tags to fix this see https://jsfiddle.net/Lfuq5qb6/1/

```
<img class="normal-logo hidden-xs" src="..." alt="logo" ondragstart="return false;"/> 

img{
    user-drag: none; 
    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: Its just stop the draging. We  need to work drag functionalty. Just hide drag or remove  image

Comment: Ah ok was unclear in your question, you still want IMG dragging to happen just the outline/ghost image hidden

Answer (score -1):

```
function removeGhosting(event) {
    if(!(event instanceof MouseEvent)) {
        console.info("Parameters must be of type MouseEvent!")
        return;
    }
    let dragIcon = document.createElement('img');
    dragIcon.src = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7',
    dragIcon.width = 0;
    dragIcon.height = 0;
    dragIcon.opacity = 0;
    if(event.dataTransfer) {
        event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(dragIcon,0, 0);
    }
}
```

[enter link description here](https://bojue.github.io/remove-drag-ghosting/)

Answer (score -6):

You can set img draggable attribute to false.

```
  <img id="" src="..." draggable="false">
```

And to disable selection on images, you can use

```
 <style>

img{
    user-drag: none; 
    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
 } 

</style>
```