# ondragstart - How to remove animation?

Tags: javascript

Whenever the user starts dragging an element with `draggable="true"`, the element has a translucent copy of the element you are dragging. Here is the example from W3Schools:
[stop starting animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsgmI.png)

Right side of the photo is important. That is the animation you get when you start dragging an element.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_ondrag

I have tried to use `event.preventDefault()`. However, the problem here is that this prevents `onDrag` from going at all while the element is moving and I need the data (mouse position and such) from  `onDrag`.

It seems there are posts out there for how to stop the animation when you drop it but not start.

Just going off the example on the W3Schools site, I want the drag information without the `ondragstart` animation.

So if I modify the code by adding a `preventDefault()` on the `ondragstart` function:

```
function dragStart(event) {
  console.log(event);
  event.preventDefault(); //stops animation in right side of photo, but then won't let ondrag fire
  event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
}

function dragging(event) {
  console.log(event);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The p element is being dragged";
}
```

The animation you get when dragging goes away. However (as shown by my `console.log)` lines, the `ondrag` won't fire with this `preventDefault` on `ondragstart`. This is the information I need.

`preventDefault` inside `ondrag` doesn't stop that animation. Is this even possible?

**SOLUTION**
If anyone is wondering, I found what I needed to do in this case. You can set the image in javascript to a transparent one:
[How to remove drag(Ghost) image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38655964/how-to-remove-dragghost-image)
so drag is still technically running but that ghostly image is gone. Wasn't thinking of right search terms.

Comment: can you explain in more detail what you want to achive? i am not if you want the copy to disapear or just want the drag infos (mouse position...)

Comment: I just need the drag infos without seeing the draggable element being dragged (via that animation).

Comment: You can add snippet to show your html/css code. Prefer copy/paste than show code as png ;)

Comment: @Elikill58 My bad, I added more to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is wondering, I found what I needed to do in this case. You can set the image in JavaScript to a transparent one:
[How to remove drag(Ghost) image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38655964/how-to-remove-dragghost-image)
so drag is still technically running but that ghostly image is gone. Wasn't thinking of right search terms.

Answer (score 0):

In this case i would go for a different approach:
https://codepen.io/deibl31/pen/oNeXmPE?editors=1111

```
// HTML
<div id="myDiv">
</div>

// CSS
#myDiv {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

// JS
let myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
let mouseDown = false;
let divPos = {x: 0, y: 0};

myDiv.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
  mouseDown = true;
});

window.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
  if (mouseDown) {
    divPos.x = event.clientX;
    divPos.y = event.clientY;    
  }
});
 
window.addEventListener('mouseup', (event) => {
  if (mouseDown) {
    myDiv.style.top = divPos.y + 'px';
    myDiv.style.left = divPos.x + 'px';
  }
  mouseDown = false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Is there no way to use the drag events? More of my issue is I need the `onclick` event as well and I think these two interfere with each other.

Comment: I don't think so. The default behaviour of the browser handles this drag animation. onmousedown` and `onclick` fire at the same time. So you can use the event from the `onclick` as well. If you have an example of your last question i could have a look at it.