# Dragged element text is sticked to cursor as "hologram"/"shadow"

Tags: html, css, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm trying to make an element draggable. It contains text and as soon as I drag the element outside the element boundaries, this weird clone of the text forms that is only slightly visible and bound to the mouse pointer with a slight offset.

How can I prevent this weird mockup?
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Adding `unselectable="on"` to the text tag in my html document unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: Seems exact the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38655964/how-to-remove-dragghost-image